# Alpine 3.6 Docker container error on stop (exit code 137)

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

Container running on Ubuntu 16.04

Below how I do (Random name `sad_wiles` created):

```
docker run -it -d alpine /bin/ash
docker run -it -d alpine /bin/sh
docker run -ti -d alpine
```

`docker start sad_wiles` running fine and I can enter & exit `sh`

However, `docker stop sad_wiles` giving exit code 137. Below is the log:

```
2017-11-25T23:22:25.301992880+08:00 container kill 61ea1f10c98e2462f496f9048dcc6b45e536d3f7ba14747f7f22b96afb2db60d (image=alpine, name=sad_wiles, signal=15)
2017-11-25T23:22:35.302560688+08:00 container kill 61ea1f10c98e2462f496f9048dcc6b45e536d3f7ba14747f7f22b96afb2db60d (image=alpine, name=sad_wiles, signal=9)
2017-11-25T23:22:35.328791538+08:00 container die 61ea1f10c98e2462f496f9048dcc6b45e536d3f7ba14747f7f22b96afb2db60d (exitCode=137, image=alpine, name=sad_wiles)
2017-11-25T23:22:35.547890765+08:00 network disconnect 3b36d7a71af5a43f0ee3cb95c159514a6d5a02d0d5d8cf903f51d619d6973b35 (container=61ea1f10c98e2462f496f9048dcc6b45e536d3f7ba14747f7f22b96afb2db60d, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2017-11-25T23:22:35.647073922+08:00 container stop 61ea1f10c98e2462f496f9048dcc6b45e536d3f7ba14747f7f22b96afb2db60d (image=alpine, name=sad_wiles)
```

Comment: This is not an error. You are stoping the container, and the logs show that. What are u expecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an error as mentioned in the comment by @yament You'll see this exit code when you do a docker stop and the initial graceful stop fails and docker has to do a sigkill. As mentioned [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html), it's a linux standard: 128 + 9 = 137 (9 coming from SIGKILL).

You can increase your memory limit in Docker App > Preferences > Advanced on Mac os. As changing this `mem_limit=384m` to 512m works. Here is additional resunce will help you, [Exit Status](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#exit-status)

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious about how sad_wiles name appeared as your container name, that has been a Docker feature from early days. If you do not specify a name for your Docker container using --name tag with your Docker run command, Docker will create a name for the container based on an open source list of scientist and hackers. You can get its source code from [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go).

The signal code issue may be due to the memory limit is low for Docker. A github issue was also opened on this. Refer it from [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21083). Try changing the memory allocation for Docker as the comments for the attached github issue recommend.